# Exclude dependency in gradle 7

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I want to exclude the following dependency in build.gradle in a module, but it doesn't work

```
        implementation("org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-impl") {
    exclude group: 'org.codehaus.woodstox', module: 'woodstox-core-asl'
    }
```

I still get the following dependency tree:

```
+--- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-impl -> 1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-api:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-api:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.36
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.36
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-api:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-api:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.36
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings:1.1.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-api:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.chemistry.opencmis:chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:3.0.12 -> 3.4.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:1.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.2 -> 3.5.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.5 -> 2.3.7 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.2.7 -> 6.3.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:2.3.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:3.4.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.2 -> 3.5.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:3.4.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.2 -> 3.5.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.3
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.0
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:3.4.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.2 -> 3.5.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |         \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:3.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:3.4.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.2 -> 3.5.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:3.4.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.2 -> 3.5.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:3.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:3.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:3.4.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.2 -> 3.5.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:3.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |         \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:3.4.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |              +--- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.3
|    |    |    |    |    |    |              +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.2 -> 3.5.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |              \--- org.apache.neethi:neethi:3.1.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |                   \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |                        +--- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2 -> org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    |                        \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4 -> 4.2.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.12 -> 3.4.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.4.2 -> 3.5.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.36
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:3.0.12 -> 3.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.12 -> 3.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:3.0.12 -> 3.4.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.36
```

This is gradle groovy. I'm using gradle 7. I already read these pages but nothing seems to help:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html

https://tomgregory.com/how-to-exclude-gradle-dependencies/

Comment: You're missing a `-` before `impl`: The artifact name ends in `-client-impl`, but you wrote `-clientimpl` (you're also missing a version number, but that might be comming from some BOM).

Comment: Thanks for noticing. It was a bad copy paste from somewhere or I accidentally removed it here, but in my code it is with -client-impl. So that's not it.

Also the version is not needed apparently.

Comment: With the fixed name and a version, your code worked just fine for me (excluding the dependency).